# How to create table array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-table

I would like to store multiple tables in one array. In my code below, I am creating two tables `T1` and `T2`. I want to store these tables into one variable `MyArray`.

```
LastName = {'Sanchez';'Johnson';'Li';'Diaz';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Smoker = logical([1;0;1;0;1]);
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];
T1 = table(LastName,Age,Smoker);
T2 = table(Height,Weight,BloodPressure);

% The code below does not work
MyArray(1) = T1;
MyArray(2) = T2;
```

I know I can use a cell array but I would like to know if it is possible to create a `table` datatype array in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `table` already implements `()` indexing, it's not really clear to me how you would expect to index `MyArray`. Your example almost looks to me like `MyArray = [T1, T2]`.

I'm not sure if it satisfies your needs, but you can have `table` objects with `table` variables, like this:

```
T = table(T1, T2);
```

You can then using indexing as normal, e.g.

```
T.T1.LastName{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a time when

```
builtin('subsref',T1,substruct('()',{1}))
```

(for any custom class `T1`<sup>*</sup>) would skip calling the class-specific overloaded `subsref` and use the built-in method instead. This would be equivalent to `T1(1)`, but ignoring whatever the class defined for that syntax. Similarly for `subsasgn`, which is the subscripted assignment operation `T1(2)=T2`. This allowed the creation and use of arrays of a class.

However, this seems to no longer work. Maybe it is related to the `classdef`-style classes, as the last time I used the trick above was before those were introduced.

I would suggest that you use cell arrays for this (even if the above still worked, I would not recommend it).

<sup>* Note that `table` is a custom class, you can `edit table` to see the source code.</sup>